# How to Get cURL Working in a Databricks Cluster?

Tags: apache-spark, curl, databricks

I have a notebook running on a cluster in Databricks. I am trying to download a .jar file from an archive online using the command:

```
$sh curl -k -O https://repository.mapr.com/nexus/content/groups/mapr-public/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/2.1.1-mapr-1803/hive-jdbc-2.1.1-mapr-1803.jar
```

When I run this on my local machine it works fine, and the .jar file successfully downloads. When I run it on Databricks, it runs indefinitely, never downloading any data. The output looks like:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:03 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:05 --:--:--     0
```

How can I overcome this and successfully download the file into my cluster?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to download the jar file into databricks without any issue.

[image]

You may try the below options to download the jar file in databricks:

**Option1:** Curl does not follow redirects by default. To tell it to do so, add the `-L` argument:

```
%sh curl  -L -k -O https://repository.mapr.com/nexus/content/groups/mapr-public/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/2.1.1-mapr-1803/hive-jdbc-2.1.1-mapr-1803.jar
```

[image]

If you still face same issue, you may use "wget" option.

**Note:** On a high-level, both wget and curl are command line utilities that do the same thing.

**Option2:** The following example downloads the file and stores in the same name as the remote server.

```
%sh wget https://repository.mapr.com/nexus/content/groups/mapr-public/org/apache/hive/hive-jdbc/2.1.1-mapr-1803/hive-jdbc-2.1.1-mapr-1803.jar --no-check-certificate
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.